# Put string into textbox -> not complete

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebresponse

I clicked together a small WinForms app for testing. It has two multiline textboxes and a single button, which on press sends a request to a server and posts response headers and content into the textboxes like this:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
int len = 0;
foreach (var header in response.Headers)
{
    var str = header.ToString();
    textBox1.AppendText(str + "=" + response.Headers[str] + "\n");
    if (str == "Content-Length") len = Convert.ToInt32(response.Headers[str]);
}
Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
byte[] x = new byte[len];
respStream.Read(x, 0, len);
var s = new string(ascii.GetChars(x, 0, len));
// textBox2.Text = s;
textBox2.Clear();
textBox2.AppendText(s);
MessageBox.Show(textBox2.TextLength.ToString(), s.Length.ToString());
```

But no matter whether I use AppendText or whether I assign the string, the MessageBox always shows the caption `7653` with message `3964`, and the headers textbox contains the line `Content-length=7653`.

So it seems that the string is not completely appended to the TextBox. Why would that be?

Btw: I am requesting an HTML document; the last two chars shown are ".5", and the first two chars missing are "16", so it does not break at some special characters.

Comment: That's a convoluted way to read a response as string. What is the value of `len`? Why not just use `string response = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, my day-to-day C# experience went by without any streams at all, and with these endless possibilities combining different objects, I guess I can't automatically find the smartest solution on the first try... although it works with your snippet, I would still like to know what went wrong in my code. `if (str == "Content-Length") len = Convert.ToInt32(response.Headers[str]);` should answer your question "What is the value of `len`?"

Comment: I can read code, I can't mentally debug it. I ask because you must inspect it at runtime. You also must check the return value of `Stream.Read` and call it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966389/need-help-understanding-stream-read)

Your problem is that with Stream.Read you may read less than the total number of characters as they may not be available yet on the network.

So your string already contains only the first part of the text. s.Length indicates the right number of characters as it gets copied over from the byte array x but most of the characters are 0 (Char '\0'). textBox2.TextLength then indicates the right number of characters that have been read. I suppose it trims the '\0' characters.

You should use a while loop instead and check the result of Read as indicated before.

Also check the encoding of your html page. For UTF8 (default in HTML 5) one byte doesn't necessarily correspond to one character.