# Serialisation error "The input stream is not a valid binary format"

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, deserialization

I'm writing a program that needs to send data from a client to a server over a TCP socket.

I have the following code that serialises and desirialises the object.

```
public static byte[] serializeObjects(Object obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }     
    }  
public static Object deserialiseObject(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

The code that sends the the serialised data from the server from the client.

```
while ((userInput = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                byte[] serialisedObject;
                serialisedObject = serializeObjects(userInput);
                byte[] userDataBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)serialisedObject.Length);
                _writer.Write(userDataBytes);
                _writer.Write(serialisedObject);
                _writer.Flush();
```

And the code that receives the serialised data from the stream.

```
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket, true);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            byte[] readMsgLeng = new byte[4];
            stream.Read(readMsgLeng, 0, 4);

            int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(readMsgLeng, 0);
            byte[] messageData = new byte[dataLength];
            stream.Read(messageData, 0, dataLength);
            returnedObject = deserialiseObject(messageData);
```

The error that is occuring is as follows "The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are:......"

Not sure what it is that is causing the error.

Comment: In the receive function, the line `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);` looks unnecessary.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3966417/4074081) answer and see example from `Read` method documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)