# fail to read it all into memory when shortcount reading

Tags: c#, .net, io

My textbook says:

**Read receives a block of data from the stream into an array. It returns the number of
bytes received, which is always either less than or equal to the count argument. If
it’s less than count, it means either that the end of the stream has been reached or
the stream is giving you the data in smaller chunks (as is often the case with network streams). In either case, the balance of bytes in the array will remain unwritten, their previous values preserved.
With Read, you can be certain you’ve reached the end of the
stream only when the method returns 0. So, if you have a
1,000-byte stream, the following code may fail to read it all
into memory:**

```
// Assuming s is a stream:
byte[] data = new byte [1000];
s.Read (data, 0, data.Length);
```

**The Read method could read anywhere from 1 to 1,000 bytes,
leaving the balance of the stream unread.**

I'm confused and I write a simple concolse application to verify:

```
//read.txt only contains 3 chars: abc
using (FileStream s = new FileStream("read.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
   byte[] data = new byte[5];
   int num = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
   foreach (byte b in data)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(b);
   }
}
```

and the output is:

> 97
>
> 98
>
> 99
>
> 0
>
> 0

so the data array has been written, why the textbook says "the balance of bytes in the array will remain unwritten and it may fail to read it all into memory",

EDIT: please discard my previous console application, the real question I have is:

a file has 1000 byte and I'm requesting to read all 1000 bytes:

```
byte[] data = new byte [1000];
s.Read (data, 0, data.Length);
```

why it may fail to read it all into memory? and the textbook also provides a correct method to read all 1000 bytes:

```
byte[] data = new byte [1000];
int bytesRead = 0;
int chunkSize = 1;
while (bytesRead < data.Length && chunkSize > 0)
 bytesRead +=
 chunkSize = s.Read (data, bytesRead, data.Length - bytesRead);
```

Comment: you can notice `s.Read` returns an integer - the number of bytes read

Comment: Sten is correct. Most of the **bold** text (`It returns`) is in reference to `num`. In summary, all it means is 'if you ask to read 1000 bytes, you'll get **up to** 1000 bytes - you won't get the whole file if it is > 1000 bytes, and you'll get less than 1000 bytes if the file is < 1000 bytes'. That is the crux of the **bold** text. When it talks about the `balance of bytes` it means those 0s you are seeing. See how they are 0 (the default). That is effectively unwritten. That data **did not** come from the file.

Comment: If you call `Read` on a stream, it is not guaranteed that you can at once read all bytes from the stream (actually in most cases you don't). The number of bytes read might be smaller than your buffer size, leaving the rest of your buffer unwritten (in your case, the trailing zeros in your array). So you should advance your read starting point by the bytes read in a loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966389/need-help-understanding-stream-read may be worth a read @slowjams.

Comment: @mjwills  so why  with a 1,000-byte stream, the code may fail to read it all into memory?if a file has 3 bytes, and I'm requesting to read 3 bytes, why I can't read 3 bytes all in once?

Comment: @slowjams because `Read` *could* read just one byte at a time. And it would be *perfectly valid implementation* of `Stream.Read` by some other derived class - trying one implementation of an interface/abstract class does not immediately show how all other implementations will behave.

Comment: `if a file has 3 bytes, and I'm requesting to read 3 bytes, why I can't read 3 bytes all in once?` At one level the answer is **because that is what the docs say**. Maybe, for example, the file is a long way away (`as is often the case with network streams`) and it is more efficient to pass you data one byte at a time (obviously that is an exaggeration - but it may choose to pass 4096 bytes when you asking for 30,000, for example). Either way - the reason _why_ is irrelevant. The docs are saying it _might_ happen so you need to make sure your code handles it.

Comment: Typical of a network stream, TCP guarantees that the bytes stuffed into a stream at one end will fall out the other end in the same order and without loss or duplication. An application may `Write` several _messages_, e.g. 10-, 20- and 50-bytes. (NB: Streams deal in _bytes_, not _messages_ or larger constructs.) As the data traverses the network from node to node different connection types, buffer sizes, delays, ..., may cause the 80-bytes of data to be fragmented and combined _arbitrarily_. The receiving application must execute `Read` as often as needed to eventually receive the 80-bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it’s less than count, it means either that the end of the stream has been reached or the stream is giving you the data in smaller chunks (as is often the case with network streams). In either case, the balance of bytes in the array will remain unwritten, their previous values preserved.

When the text says `In either case`, it refers to `If it’s (the return value, i.e the bytes read from the stream) less than count`. In this case, the bytes read don't take up all the buffer area you have designated to the read action. The rest of the buffer area is, of course, untouched (`remain unwritten, their previous values preserved`).

In your case, it is that `the end of the stream has been reached` because you only have 3 bytes in your file stream. The trailing zeros in your array are the untouched buffer elements.

> So, if you have a 1,000-byte stream, the following code may fail to read it all into memory.

The text is talking about a 1,000-byte stream, while your stream just contains 3 bytes. For a short file stream that has only 3 bytes, it is likely that all data will be loaded into memory at once, which is the case you have observed. (**just "likely", not "guaranteed"**). For a longer stream (or other types of stream, e.g. `NetworkStream`), you are not guarunteed to read bytes enough to fill your designated buffer area at once (there are possibilities that you may even get only 1 bytes at a time!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the first part, but for the second part, does it mean there is a timeout mechanism for a stream? let's say a stream needs to read 1000 bytes, but the current networkis slow and only provide 500 bytes and is hanging, and a timeout happens, so only 500 bytes is read into the buffer?

Comment: @slowjams On a network data arrive in unit called `Packet`. It's like receiving mail in your letter box. You rarely wait until your mailbox (buffer) is full to take out mails and read.

Comment: Thanks for the analogous example. I think I misunderstand  sth fundamentally. when we say a 1,000-byte stream, since a stream can only read one byte per time, does it mean that the stream has read 1000 times from data source? could you put the concept of stream in your mailbox example please?

Comment: `when we say a 1,000-byte stream, since a stream can only read one byte per time, does it mean that the stream has read 1000 times from data source?` @slowjams To be blunt, why do you care how it works? What you need to do is ensure that you read the value of `num` to see how many bytes were read. Everything else is an implementation detail over which you have no control, and which may change in future.

Comment: @mjwills  Thanks for the link. So can I say for FileStream, there will never be short counts, if I want to read 1,000 bytes in once from a file, I will always get `num`  equals to 1000? short count will only happen in network stream?

Comment: No, you can't say that @slowjams. You can only say what the docs say. The docs don't promise that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.8 is explicit - `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.8`), so you can't rely on that. Once again - **why do you care?**

Comment: I care because if I just want to read a file, I don't need to consider short counts, so I can just issue one read instead of a loop while read.  I checked another textbook(classic CSAPP) which says:" In practice, you will never encounter short counts when you read from disk files except on EOF, and you will never encounter short counts when you write to disk files. However, if you want to build robust (reliable) network applications such as Web servers, then you must deal with short counts by repeatedly calling read and write", isn't that means only network stream can experience short counts?

Comment: @slowjams `In practice` is another way of saying 'based on current implementations and based on my experience' (neither of which are guarantees for the future). Also, that comment only mentions two types of streams (disk and network) when there are many more. Regardless, my point is this - **you have no control over this anyway, so just write your code in the suggested way which is to check the return value**. Then, whether it is a network stream or memory stream or file stream or some other stream you've never heard about **you don't care**. It will just work.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to:

```
byte[] data = new byte[5];
int num = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
foreach (byte b in data)
```

That `foreach` will process every single byte in `data` (and there's *always* five of those regardless of how many were written to by the `Read()` call).

The number of bytes that were actually read by the `Read()` call gets stored into the `num` variable, so *that's* what you should be using to process your data, something like (untested but probably simple enough to not warrant it):

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
}
```

As per the text you quote, everything after the bytes that were read can be any arbitrary value because the `Read()` call did not change them. In your case, they were obviously zero before the `Read()` and so remained so.

If you were to run that `foreach` loop before the `Read()` as well as after, you should see only the first three bytes change (assuming the content of the file is different to what was in memory, of course).